# Multiple Choice Question type setting for options

Tags: exam

In the following code we are getting answers of each questions in following ways
[1]    (a) (b) (c) (d) i.e. in (4-columns)
[2]    (a) (b)
       (c) (d) i.e. in (2-columns)
according to the length of the answers. Its good....

Is there any correction in this code, if i want to produced all four options in a single column, i mean like
(a)
(b)
(c)
(d) (1-column)
in my question bank there are lots of question having some good length of options and it is not possible to get output mentioned [1] and [2] forms.

Please provide some better solution for this code, i almost completed my works except few questions by using this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    %usage \choice{ }{ }{ }{ }
    %(A)(B)(C)(D)
    \newcommand{\fourch}[4]{
    \par
            \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.23\textwidth}}}
            (a)~#1 & (b)~#2 & (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
            \end{tabular}
    }

    %(A)(B)
    %(C)(D)
    \newcommand{\twoch}[4]{

            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
            (a)~#1 & (b)~#2
            \end{tabular}
    \par
            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
            (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
            \end{tabular}
    }

    %(A)
    %(B)
    %(C)
    %(D)
    \newcommand{\onech}[4]{
    \par
          (a)~#1 \par (b)~#2 \par (c)~#3 \par (d)~#4
    }

    \newlength\widthcha
    \newlength\widthchb
    \newlength\widthchc
    \newlength\widthchd
    \newlength\widthch
    \newlength\tabmaxwidth

    \setlength\tabmaxwidth{0.96\textwidth}
    \newlength\fourthtabwidth
    \setlength\fourthtabwidth{0.25\textwidth}
    \newlength\halftabwidth
    \setlength\halftabwidth{0.5\textwidth}

  \newcommand{\choice}[4]{%
  \settowidth\widthcha{AM.#1}\setlength{\widthch}{\widthcha}%
  \settowidth\widthchb{BM.#2}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
  \settowidth\widthchb{CM.#3}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
  \settowidth\widthchb{DM.#4}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
  \ifdim\widthch<\fourthtabwidth
    \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
    \ifdim\widthch>\fourthtabwidth
      \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \else
      \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \fi
  \fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
\question If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram
representing az, 3az and - az are
\choice{Vertices of a right angled triangle}{ Vertices of an equilateral 
triangle}{Vertices of an isosceles triangle}{Collinear}
\question If z represents a complex number then $\arg (z) + \arg\left(\bar z\right)$ is 
\choice{$\dfrac{\pi}{4}$}{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$}{0}{$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$}
\question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
\choice{ purely imaginary}{purely real}{0}{neither real nor imaginary}
\question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is
\choice{i}{-i}{1}{-1}
\question The volume generated by 
rotating the triangle with vertices at
(0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is
\choice{$18\pi$}{$2\pi$}{$36\pi$}{$9\pi$}\end{questions}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get single-column answers the `\ifdim` sequence needs to be altered a little bit. The sequence should be: if the longest answer fits in 1/4, put four columns, else if the longest answer fits in 1/2 width, put 2 columns, else put 1 column.

Also, the length assignments for the four answers was incorrect (b is used for b,c, and d). MWE with these corrections:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    %usage \choice{ }{ }{ }{ }
    %(A)(B)(C)(D)
    \newcommand{\fourch}[4]{
    \par
            \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.23\textwidth}}}
            (a)~#1 & (b)~#2 & (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
            \end{tabular}
    }

    %(A)(B)
    %(C)(D)
    \newcommand{\twoch}[4]{

            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
            (a)~#1 & (b)~#2
            \end{tabular}
    \par
            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
            (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
            \end{tabular}
    }

    %(A)
    %(B)
    %(C)
    %(D)
    \newcommand{\onech}[4]{
    \par
          (a)~#1 \par (b)~#2 \par (c)~#3 \par (d)~#4
    }

    \newlength\widthcha
    \newlength\widthchb
    \newlength\widthchc
    \newlength\widthchd
    \newlength\widthch
    \newlength\tabmaxwidth

    \setlength\tabmaxwidth{0.96\textwidth}
    \newlength\fourthtabwidth
    \setlength\fourthtabwidth{0.25\textwidth}
    \newlength\halftabwidth
    \setlength\halftabwidth{0.5\textwidth}

  \newcommand{\choice}[4]{%
  \settowidth\widthcha{AM.#1}\setlength{\widthch}{\widthcha}%
  \settowidth\widthchb{BM.#2}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
  \settowidth\widthchc{CM.#3}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchc\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchc}\fi%
  \settowidth\widthchd{DM.#4}%
  \ifdim\widthch<\widthchd\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchd}\fi%
  \ifdim\widthch<\fourthtabwidth
    \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
      \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \else
      \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
\question If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram
representing az, 3az and - az are
\choice{Vertices of a right angled triangle}{ Vertices of an equilateral 
triangle}{Vertices of an isosceles triangle}{Collinear}
\question If z represents a complex number then $\arg (z) + \arg\left(\bar z\right)$ is 
\choice{$\dfrac{\pi}{4}$}{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$}{0}{$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$}
\question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
\choice{ purely imaginary}{purely real}{0}{neither real nor imaginary}
\question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is
\choice{i}{-i}{1}{-1}
\question The volume generated by 
rotating the triangle with vertices at
(0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is
\choice{$18\pi$}{$2\pi$}{$36\pi$}{$9\pi$}
\question A question with very long answers 
\choice{This answer is very long and will need the full width of the page to display which leads to a single column}{This answer, like the first, is very long and will need the full width of the page to display which leads to a single column}{This answer, like the second is very long and will need the full width of the page to display which leads to a single column}{This answer, like the third, is very long and will need the full width of the page to display which leads to a single column}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Note that your MWE had two `\end{document}` statements.

Remark: the question was not entirely clear (I hope this solution is what you need). For future reference, please provide an example of what goes wrong, in this case a question with long answers.

Comment: @marjin can we achieve the same in scrartcl class for a two column document using the enumerate \item builtin

Comment: @nichas that is a rather different situation, it would be best if you ask a new question about this using the Ask Question button. In your new question you can provide a link to this question for reference.

Comment: Thanks!! will do it.